# How to remove JavaFX stage buttons (minimize, maximize, close)

Tags: javafx-2

How to remove JavaFX stage buttons (minimize, maximize, close)? Can't find any according `Stage` methods, so should I use style for the stage? It's necessary for implementing Dialog windows like `Error`, `Warning`, `Info`.

Answer (score 83):

If you want to disable only the maximize button then use :

```
stage.resizableProperty().setValue(Boolean.FALSE);
```

or if u want to disable maximize and minimize except close use

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
```

or if you want to remove all three then use

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```

Answer (score 26):

You just have to set a stage's style. Try this example:

```
package undecorated;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class UndecoratedApp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 100, 100);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

When learning JavaFX 2.0 [these examples](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/javafx/2.0.1/javafx_samples-2_0_1.zip) are very helpful.

Comment: `primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);` makes a window with no header. How can I remove just the minimize/maximize/close buttons?

Comment: @Chechulin How can I remove just the minimize/maximize/close buttons?
There is no option for this now. I tried to remove only minimize for Login. But failed.

Answer (score 13):

```
primaryStage.setResizable(false);
```

Answer (score 11):

```
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
```

Comment: +1: minimize and maximize buttons removed. Add setOnClose() handler with event.consume() to inhibit close button (workaround).

Comment: Good suggestion @Aubin. However the correct event is `setOnCloseRequest`

    primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(final WindowEvent windowEvent) {                
                    windowEvent.consume();                
            }
        });

Comment: Java 8 style: primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest((event) -> event.consume());

Answer (score 9):

I´m having the same issue, seems like an undecorated but draggable/titled window (for aesthetic sake) is not possible in javafx at this moment. The closest approach is to consume the close event.

```
stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                    event.consume();
                }
            });
```

If you like lambdas

```
stage.setOnCloseRequest(e->e.consume());
```

Comment: It is consume the event not remove the close button !

Comment: "an undecorated but draggable/titled window (for aesthetic sake) is not possible in javafx at this moment" Has that changed since you wrote this? I'm making a JavaFX app now, and I wish I could edit the Stage itself the same way I can edit the Scene.

Answer (score 4):

```
stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
stage.setResizable(false);
```

Comment: please give more info about the solution you gave just pasting some code is less helpfull

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer here --> 
http://javafxportal.blogspot.ie/2012/03/to-remove-javafx-stage-buttons-minimize.html
We can do it:

```
enter code here
 @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 100, 100);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED);
stage.setResizable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this, you call the following methods on your stage object

```
stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL); // makes stage act as a modal
stage.setMinWidth(250); // sets stage width
stage.setMinHeight(250); // sets stage height
stage.setResizable(false); // prevents resize and removes minimize and maximize buttons
stage.showAndWait(); // blocks execution until the stage is closed
```