# Using stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY) remove icon from task bar

Tags: javafx

[Make close button disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341305/how-to-remove-javafx-stage-buttons-minimize-maximize-close)

I wanted to make my screen resizable and I tried my jfx code by refering above link. But this is hiding the icon of my application from task bar ?

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The linked answer suggests `StageStyle.UNDECORATED` not `StageStyle.UTILITY`.