# How to change tooltip text of a JavaFX stage default close (aka 'X') button?

Tags: java, button, javafx, dialog, tooltip

I have a simple JavaFX stage. It has a default close button on the upper right corner. When user drags mouse over it and wait a while, "Close" tooltip appears. I need to change the text of that tooltip. Is there any way to achieve this?

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Stage Screenshot]

Comment: i am not quite sure about javafx but as i know in swing it is not possible to set the tooltip for that button

Comment: Remove the default buttons and create your own.   How to remove default buttons->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341305/how-to-remove-javafx-stage-buttons-minimize-maximize-close  Help recreating buttons->http://www.programering.com/q/MjN1UTNwATg.html

Comment: @Sedrick Jefferson, I will probably do that as no other way seems possible.

Comment: If all you need is a custom close button it is very simple.

Comment: @Sedrick Jefferson, I know and I will do that. Thanks for your answer.